# SSL Error Encountered When Executing SSIS Package (Containing Call to Python Code) from SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: sql-server, ssl, ssis, ssl-certificate, sql-server-agent

My SSIS package consists of an Execute Process Task which executes some compiled python code which downloads files from a Web API.

The code works.
The package executes succesfully from Visual Studio.
Once deployed to my localhost sql server 2012 instance SSISDB, I can right click execute it and it works fine.

However, as soon as I try to invoke the package from a SQL Server Agent job, it fails with. I do not understand this but I suspect this is because I don't understand what's happening with the SSL handshake. Does SQL Server Agent reference it's own store? If so, does this mean that my store is inactivated (do I need to enable SSL for my sql server agent?) or missing a certificate?

It feels like I have tried every possible workaround - I have ensured that my sql server agent is owned by my credential, rather than a generic credential - I've even created a proxy and explicitly instructed the sql server agent job step to run under that proxy but I guess this isn't the issue. The issue is the SSL certification step.

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you try to view the execution report for the failure one from SSISDB, to see the details?

Comment: Huh? Yes, the details show an SSL Error validating the certificate. That comes from the error traceback of my program. I need to understand why sql server agent is not using the same SSL store that my machine uses so that I can then fix it.